# C++ Pointer to 2D Dynamic Array?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, multidimensional-array

I am a bit of a C++ newbie and I am working on a project and I a little stuck. I need to create a dynamic 2D ragged array then have a pointer point to it. Here is what I have:

```
int ** x = new int*[3];
int *** y = ???;
```

Now, after I do:

```
x[n] = new int[length];
x[++n] = new int[length2];
//etc etc
```

I can access the values in the array through a statement like:

```
int num = x[i][j];
```

What I want is to be able to the same array values through y like:

```
int num2 = *y[i][j];
```

So, in this case, num2 and num should have the same value, how would I go about allocating the memory for y and assigning it?

Thanks!

Comment: As a "C++ newbie", do yourself a favor and forget that you ever even heard of `new`, especially the array form of `new`. For a ragged 2D array, use `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`.

Comment: The project is for a class and the design spec indicates that that we are not to use vectors.

Comment: Then fire your teacher and find one who has a clue what's he's doing. Sorry to be so blunt, but this is utterly inexcusable behavior on his part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of creating a 2D array in C++.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  // dimensions
  int N = 3;
  int M = 3;

  // dynamic allocation
  int** ary = new int*[N];
  for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
      ary[i] = new int[M];

  // fill
  for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j < M; ++j)
      ary[i][j] = i;

  // print
  for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j < M; ++j)
      std::cout << ary[i][j] << "\n";

  // free
  for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    delete(ary[i]);
  delete [] ary;

  return 0;
}

// OUTPUT
0
0
0
1
1
1
2
2
2
```

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936687/how-do-i-declare-a-2d-array-in-c-using-new) answer too for more.

So now, you have created the 2D array. You want just a pointer to point to it. You do not need to allocate memory again (this would be wrong)!

So, you just need to do something like this:

```
  int ***p = &ary;

  // print
  for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j < M; ++j)
      std::cout << (*p)[i][j] << "\n";
```

...but wait, it's C++! You should use std::array or std::vector instead of primitive arrays (expanding them for 2D, like std::vector< std::vector  >)!

Answer (score 0):

A pointer to x would be:

```
int *** y = &x;
```

There is no need to allocate space for y.

Comment: Doesn't that make y point to x? I want y to point to a pointer that is pointing to what x is pointing to